# Definition of the covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, intuition, tensors, lie-derivative

In Peter Petersen's book *Riemannian Geometry* (2. Edition) the covariant derivative on a Riemannian manifold is defined by the implicit formula

$$2g(\nabla_YX,Z)=(L_Xg)(Y,Z)+(d\theta_X)(Y,Z)$$

where $(L_Xg)$ is the Lie derivative of the metric and $\theta_X$ is the one form given by $\theta_X(Y)=g(X,Y)$. Then it is shown that this is the uniquely determined metric and torsion free affine connection.

I understand that $X$ is locally a gradient field iff $d\theta_X=0$ so $d\theta_X$ measures in some sense how far $X$ is away from being a gradient field.  Also i think i understand what $(L_Xg)(Y,Z)$ is: we let $(Y,Z)$ flow along $X$ and measure the infinitesimal change after applying the metric.

The way i see the covariant derivative is to embedd the Riemannian manifold into some $ \mathbb R^N$ and then take the tangential part of the usual derivative. This makes perfectly sense to me. Of course by the uniqueness part these two definitions agree.

Beside that i don't understand why the above formula is a sensible definition. What does it geometrically mean that the derivative splits into these two parts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula is a concise and expressive [version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216275/2002) of Koszul formula. This is just the matter of [regrouping](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1671882/2002) the terms.

It shows that the Levi-Civita covariant derivative is given with a formula, which employs only the Lie derivative, the exterior derivative, and the given Riemannian metric.

I find this formula very illuminating, because the Lie derivative and the exterior derivative are always present on a smooth manifold (do not require any choice), and the only choice is made when a Riemannian metric is fixed.

This formula also exhibits the important properties of the covariant derivative: it is linear in $Y$ and non-linear in $X$.

Furthermore, in reveals that the Levi-Civita covariant derivative depends on the Lie derivative of the metric, which is the source of non-linearity on the slot $X$. This observation may also lead to other interesting insights.